# LINQ and C#: How to add a field, not mapped to a table column

Tags: c#, linq

I load records from a database table. I need to add a field called "temp", which does not correspond to any table column. How can I add this field?

```
namespace mynamespace.Models
{
    public class alert
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string temp { get; set; } //<--- this generates error
    }
}
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Why you want to add this property?

Comment: I need store and pass a calculated value to the front end CSHTML pages. Thanks for chiming in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `[NotMapped]` attribute.

```
[NotMapped]
public string temp { get; set; }
```

Any property or class that has the `NotMapped` attribute will be excluded from database mapping.

Comment: That works! Thanks. Will select it as the answer in a few minutes. Again, thanks!